# RestSharp.Portable inner exception "The 'Content-Length' header must be modified"

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, restsharp

I am trying to use RestShart.Portable for a xamarin cross platform mobile app. For a windows .net app, I have used below piece of code with RestSharp and it is working fine. However as soon as used the same code in RestSharp.Portable with RestSharp.Portable.WebRequest, I am getting following inner exception:
"The 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name"

I have spent a lot time digging but not making any progress. I will really appreciate any help. Here is my test code:

```
var request = new RestRequest ("MyResource", Method.POST);
string postData = myJsonToPost;
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", postData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
Task task;
try
{
    task = restClient.Execute(request);
    task.Wait();
    IRestResponse response = task.Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in RestSharp.Portable and has been fixed. More details are here: https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/95